# How to find whether a word is palindrome using string instructions and assembly directives?

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm asked in an exercise to write a code that determines whether a word among a string array "string" is a palindrome or not restricting this code to implement .repeat-untilcxz, esi and edi registers. My idea is to point esi at the beginning of the word and edi at the end. However, I believe to use also instructions such as cmpsb, movsb, and scasb which had been introduced in the book. It turns out esi and edi cannot be controlled separately to adjust their values for next word in the string array. I don't know how to combine the solution of this exercise with what I have leant so far such as cmpbs, and others. Assuming this code seems like,

```
.686
.model flat, c
.stack 100h
scanf   PROTO   arg2:Ptr Byte, inputlist:VARARG
printf  PROTO   arg1:Ptr Byte, printlist:VARARG


.data
msg1fmt byte 0Ah,"%s",0
msg2fmt byte 0Ah,"%s",0Ah,0Ah,0
msg1 byte "The word is a palindrome",0
msg2 byte "The word is NOT a palindrome",0

string  byte "naman","numan","lapal",0

.code
main proc

mov ecx,3

mov esi,offset string
mov edi,offset string + 4
.repeat
cld
mov ebx,ecx
repe cmpsb                       
sub edi,2                     ;incorrect, because esi and edi already altered by cmpsb

.if ecx == 0
INVOKE printf, ADDR msg2fmt, ADDR msg1
.else
INVOKE printf, ADDR msg2fmt, ADDR msg2
.endif
mov ecx,ebx
lea esi,string
lea edi,string+4
add esi,5
add edi,5
.untilcxz
ret
main endp
end
```

I'm glad to see your help!

Comment: I have some other ideas for the solution but I would like to let the code as simple as possible. My opinion was to preserve another string with unknow values then I copy each word in reverse thus esi and edi could be used.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to use `rep cmpsb` here since it inherently always increments both pointers in the same direction, and you want them moving in opposite directions.  You'll have to write your own loop with conditional jumps instead of using `rep`.  You could still use `cmpsb` within the loop, but as you noted, you'll have to manually subtract 2 from `edi` on each iteration to make it effectively go backwards.   [...]

Comment: This may or may not be more efficient than a more direct implementation where you load one of the bytes into a register for comparison, and increment/decrement the pointers manually.